# Ошибка Fatal error: Class 'CModule' not found

Tags: php, битрикс

Имеется сайт на Битрикс, имеется скрипт который собирает кое-какую инфу с другого сайта с помощью библиотеки [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser Manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm), данный скрипт отрабатывает по заданию cron. По ссылке с браузера файл со скриптом отрабатывает нормально, но при запуске cron`ом на сервере выдает ошибку:

> Fatal error:  Class 'CModule' not
>   found

Покопавшись в инете, наткнулся на статью техподдержки Битрикс с описание [Как настроить работу периодических функций с использованием планировщика cron?](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/support/faq/8366/#112857) Я всё сделал по инструкции, но ошибка осталась. Потом снова наткнулся на [форум с похожей проблемой](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/forums/forum6/topic29767/) только там человек использует другую библиотекой PHPExcel.

Прикладываю кусок своего кода. На мой взгляд  конфликт идет с используемой мной библиотекой PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser Manual.

```
    #!/usr/bin/php
    <?php
            $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] = "путь указан корректный проверил 10 раз";
            $DOCUMENT_ROOT = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];

            define("NO_KEEP_STATISTIC", true);
            define("NOT_CHECK_PERMISSIONS", true);

            require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php");
            set_time_limit(86400); 

            include ('SimpleHTMLDOM/simple_html_dom.php');

            // Как написано в инструкции тут идет мой код и там встречается строка с обращением к классу для работы с модулями CModule::IncludeModule('iblock'); Ну собственно на этой строке и падает

            require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules­/main/include/epilog_after.php");
?>
```

**Подскажите пожалуйста, у кого какие мысли или идеи на этот счет есть?**

Comment: В общем, сейчас тех.поддержка Битрикса, ответила след.: В шеле и Apache используют разные php.ini, проблема в том, что не включен short_open_tag. Правильная комманда */usr/bin/php -c /mnt/datadisk/NODEL/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini -f /путь к файлу/file.php*

Буду смотреть и разбираться. Обязательно отпишусь если проблема была именно в этом, чтобы другие если наступят на эти грабли могли их обойти, ничего просто так не оставлю, всё прокомментирую, это уже мое кредо стало!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

// Как написано в инструкции тут идет мой код и там встречается строка с обращением к классу для работы с модулями CModule::IncludeModule('iblock'); Ну собственно на этой строке и падает

а вы файл класса CModule нехотите подключить?

Comment: Ну собственно вот: В служебной части пролога (файл prolog_before.php) происходит подключение к базе, отработка агентов, инициализация служебных констант, проверка прав уровня, подключение необходимых модулей (CModule - класс для работы с модулями. Все классы представляющие из себя описание конкретных модулей системы должны наследоваться от класса CModule), исполнение обработчиков событий OnPageStart, OnBeforeProlog, а также ряд других необходимых действий. Так, что все подключено ужо...!

Comment: @Ale_x, В общем, проблема была действительно связана в некорректной строкой. В комментарии описал ответ техподдержки. Так, что если кто-то столкнется с такой же проблемой, знайте, что необходимо сформировать корректную команду для запуска файла по CRON заданию. Ale_x принимаю ваш ответ, т.к вопрос считаю закрытым!

Answer (score 4):

Был аналогичный случай из-за различий конфигов, отключенной short_open_tag в частности.
для запуска достаточно добавить параметр при вызове в котором данную опцию включаешь
примерно так:

```
    php -d short_open_tag=1 test.php
```